# HTML elements overlap in IE 7 ONLY

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a page that looks great in every browser except IE 7, where the table in the center overlaps the grey section below. I have a fixed height on the center section for continuity between pages, so that needs to stay in place.

http://www.bikramyoga.cz/rozvrh.htm

I have tried to add a min-height, max-height, etc, !important declarations and the like, and nothing seems to keep the table within the 510px container.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of IE. Do what the lousy IE web developers do and put "Looks *worst* in IE"

Comment: you could try adding a conditional comment so that if IE7 push your footer box down. I know that's a work around but.. it's IE :)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem a couple of times.  Try adding:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Right after:

```
<ul id="legend">
<li><img class="rozvrh" src="img/dot.png" alt="czech class">&#268;esk&#225; lekce</li>
<li><img class="rozvrh" src="img/box.png" alt="english class">Anglick&#225; lekce</li>
<li><img class="rozvrh" src="img/dud.png" alt="babysitting">&#268;esk&#225; lekce s hl&#237;d&#225;n&#237;m d&#283;t&#237;</li>
</ul>
</div>
```